# How to install gssapi python module on windows?

Tags: python, windows, installation, kerberos, gssapi

I am currently trying to get the [gssapi module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gssapi/1.1.3) for python to run on windows. My goal is to authenticate with an Active Directory using python module [ldap3](http://ldap3.readthedocs.org/). gssapi is an requirement for this to work. However, installation fails because it cannot find krb5-config. On Linux it is easy to [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714635/how-to-install-python-module-without-setup-py). I installed [Kerberos for Windows](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/dist/index.html#kfw-4.0) but it does not have krb5-config and I could not find it anywhere else (other than for Linux). Does anyone know where to find the required tools or how to continue (if it is possible at all)?

Comment: Just ran into the same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. Apperently it does not work (at least did not work back then). I switched to C# and PowerShell for AD related tasks.

Comment: Mongo folks ported PyKerberos to use native windows SSPI, maybe give a looksee for it: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/winkerberos

Comment: ran into the same issue. Any updates on this?

Comment: I looked into this a bit (trying to get ldap3 working under MINGW64 on Windows with Kerberos auth) and it seems it looks for a libgss-3.dll that it can't find: https://github.com/pythongssapi/python-gssapi/blob/master/setup.py#L98 (it failed on the ctypes.CDLL line)
It also shows errors about krb5-config being missing though.

Comment: I have just found https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/issues/190 where someone has claimed to have ported ldap3 kerberos support to use pykerberos/winkerberos instead of gssapi.

Answer (score 4):

Following the suggestion of @keithhendry (https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/issues/190) I replaced the `kerberos.py` under `ldap3\protocol\sasl\` with [this one](https://github.com/Morgan-Stanley/treadmill/blob/master/lib/python/treadmill/ldap3kerberos.py).

In order to use Windows' GSSAPI, you also need to install the [winkerberos](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/winkerberos) package and
replace the kerberos import at line 15 in kerberos.py as follows:

```
import winkerberos as kerberos
```

This works transparently because winkerberos follows the same API structure as pykerberos, on which the edited kerberos.py was based.

Now you can use `authentication=SASL, sasl_mechanism=GSSAPI` when constructing the `Connection` with ldap3 and everything should automagically work (assuming that the other 999 things that can go wrong with Kerberos don't go wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280673/9921853), and to avoid monkey-patching, one could utilize the following code, based on file provided [there](https://github.com/Morgan-Stanley/treadmill/blob/master/lib/python/treadmill/ldap3kerberos.py) and on the `ldap3\core\connection.py` module.

### ldap3kerberos.py

```
"""Replaces the use of python-gssapi with kerberos in ldap3.
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64
import socket

import ldap3
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPCommunicationError
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.sasl import send_sasl_negotiation
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.sasl import abort_sasl_negotiation

from ldap3.protocol.sasl.external import sasl_external
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.digestMd5 import sasl_digest_md5
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.plain import sasl_plain
from ldap3.utils.log import log, log_enabled, BASIC
from ldap3 import EXTERNAL, DIGEST_MD5, GSSAPI


import winkerberos as kerberos

NO_SECURITY_LAYER = 1
INTEGRITY_PROTECTION = 2
CONFIDENTIALITY_PROTECTION = 4


class Connection(ldap3.Connection):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_sasl_bind(self,
                     controls):
        if log_enabled(BASIC):
            log(BASIC, 'start SASL BIND operation via <%s>', self)
        self.last_error = None
        with self.connection_lock:
            result = None

            if not self.sasl_in_progress:
                self.sasl_in_progress = True
                try:
                    if self.sasl_mechanism == EXTERNAL:
                        result = sasl_external(self, controls)
                    elif self.sasl_mechanism == DIGEST_MD5:
                        result = sasl_digest_md5(self, controls)
                    elif self.sasl_mechanism == GSSAPI:
                        result = sasl_gssapi(self, controls)
                    elif self.sasl_mechanism == 'PLAIN':
                        result = sasl_plain(self, controls)
                finally:
                    self.sasl_in_progress = False

            if log_enabled(BASIC):
                log(BASIC, 'done SASL BIND operation, result <%s>', result)

            return result


def sasl_gssapi(connection, controls):
    """
    Performs a bind using the Kerberos v5 ("GSSAPI") SASL mechanism
    from RFC 4752. Does not support any security layers, only authentication!
    sasl_credentials can be empty or a tuple with one or two elements.
    The first element determines which service principal to request a ticket
    for and can be one of the following:
    - None or False, to use the hostname from the Server object
    - True to perform a reverse DNS lookup to retrieve the canonical hostname
      for the hosts IP address
    - A string containing the hostname
    The optional second element is what authorization ID to request.
    - If omitted or None, the authentication ID is used as the authorization ID
    - If a string, the authorization ID to use. Should start with "dn:" or
      "user:".
    """
    # pylint: disable=too-many-branches
    target_name = None
    authz_id = b''
    if connection.sasl_credentials:
        if (len(connection.sasl_credentials) >= 1 and
                connection.sasl_credentials[0]):
            if connection.sasl_credentials[0] is True:
                hostname = \
                    socket.gethostbyaddr(connection.socket.getpeername()[0])[0]
                target_name = 'ldap@' + hostname

            else:
                target_name = 'ldap@' + connection.sasl_credentials[0]
        if (len(connection.sasl_credentials) >= 2 and
                connection.sasl_credentials[1]):
            authz_id = connection.sasl_credentials[1].encode("utf-8")
    if target_name is None:
        target_name = 'ldap@' + connection.server.host

    gssflags = (
        kerberos.GSS_C_MUTUAL_FLAG |
        kerberos.GSS_C_SEQUENCE_FLAG |
        kerberos.GSS_C_INTEG_FLAG |
        kerberos.GSS_C_CONF_FLAG
    )

    _, ctx = kerberos.authGSSClientInit(target_name, gssflags=gssflags)

    in_token = b''
    try:
        while True:
            status = kerberos.authGSSClientStep(
                ctx,
                base64.b64encode(in_token).decode('ascii')
            )
            out_token = kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(ctx) or ''
            result = send_sasl_negotiation(
                connection,
                controls,
                base64.b64decode(out_token)
            )
            in_token = result['saslCreds'] or b''
            if status == kerberos.AUTH_GSS_COMPLETE:
                break

        kerberos.authGSSClientUnwrap(
            ctx,
            base64.b64encode(in_token).decode('ascii')
        )
        unwrapped_token = base64.b64decode(
            kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(ctx) or ''
        )

        if len(unwrapped_token) != 4:
            raise LDAPCommunicationError('Incorrect response from server')

        server_security_layers = unwrapped_token[0]
        if not isinstance(server_security_layers, int):
            server_security_layers = ord(server_security_layers)
        if server_security_layers in (0, NO_SECURITY_LAYER):
            if unwrapped_token.message[1:] != '\x00\x00\x00':
                raise LDAPCommunicationError(
                    'Server max buffer size must be 0 if no security layer'
                )
        if not server_security_layers & NO_SECURITY_LAYER:
            raise LDAPCommunicationError(
                'Server requires a security layer, but this is not implemented'
            )

        client_security_layers = bytearray([NO_SECURITY_LAYER, 0, 0, 0])
        kerberos.authGSSClientWrap(
            ctx,
            base64.b64encode(
                bytes(client_security_layers) + authz_id
            ).decode('ascii')
        )
        out_token = kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(ctx) or ''

        return send_sasl_negotiation(
            connection,
            controls,
            base64.b64decode(out_token)
        )
    except (kerberos.GSSError, LDAPCommunicationError):
        abort_sasl_negotiation(connection, controls)
        raise
```

Install **winkerberos**: `pip install winkerberos`

In your script, use the following code (`connect_timeout`, `mode` and `receive_timeout` parameters are for example only and could be omitted or changed):

```
import ldap
import ldap3kerberos

server = ldap3.Server(fqdn, connect_timeout=10, mode=ldap3.IP_V4_ONLY)
conn = ldap3kerberos.Connection(
    server, authentication=ldap3.SASL, sasl_mechanism=ldap3.GSSAPI,
    auto_bind=True, receive_timeout=10
)
```

> If you have several domain controller servers for an AD domain, ensure you are connecting to some specific server, otherwise you will get the exception:
>
> `winkerberos.GSSError: SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext: The specified target is unknown or unreachable`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the `gssapi` module to install on Windows either, but I did manage to get the `ldap3` module to authenticate against Active Directory on Windows using code like this:

```
import ssl
import ldap3

tls_configuration = ldap3.Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                              version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
server = ldap3.Server(host='domaincontroller.example.com', port=636,
                      use_ssl=True, tls=tls_configuration,
                      get_info=ldap3.ALL)
con = ldap3.Connection(server, version=3,
                       auto_bind=True,
                       raise_exceptions=True,
                       user='EXAMPLE\\username',
                       password='MySecret',
                       authentication=ldap3.NTLM)
```

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't do Kerberos authentication, you have to provide the username and password. :/