# 'krb5-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python

While trying to install gssapi>=1.2.0 on Windows 10 Home X64, I get the error below. How can I solve this issue?

```
Collecting gssapi
  Using cached gssapi-1.2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    'krb5-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    In distributed package, building from C files...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File " C:….\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1d6gry0u\gssapi\setup.py", line 56, in <module>
        link_args = get_output('krb5-config --libs gssapi')
      File "C:….\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1d6gry0u\gssapi\setup.py", line 38, in _get_output
        res = subprocess.check_output(*args, shell=True, **kwargs)
      File "c:\python34\Lib\subprocess.py", line 620, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'krb5-config --libs gssapi' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710365/how-to-install-gssapi-python-module-on-windows help at all?

Answer (score 2):

According to this link the error signals about an unmet dependency:
https://github.com/pythongssapi/requests-gssapi/issues/14

So, you need a GSSAPI installation to use python-gssapi.

Comment: this also applies when trying to `pip install aws-adfs`. The solution is to do beforehand a `sudo apt install heimdal-dev` only then it works