# Passwordless Python LDAP3 authentication from Windows client

Tags: python, windows, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am using the great ldap3 package and I am trying to connect with a active directory server but without requiring to provide actual credentials in plain text.

Following SASL mechanisms are supported.
`['GSSAPI', 'GSS-SPNEGO', 'EXTERNAL', 'DIGEST-MD5']`

I tried to install the package GSSAPI but that doesn't work on my Windows machine. 
Error on  `pip install gssapi` was:
`subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'krb5-config --libs gssapi' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Can anybody provide a simple example for that?
I believe GSS-SPNEGO could be the solution but I did't find any comprehensible example in the internet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for asking this.  I gave it one last shot today and got it to work.

[See Davide's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710365/how-to-install-gssapi-python-module-on-windows)

It requires you to have the ldap3 package and to install the winkerberos package:

```
pip install winkerberos
```

Then you need to replace the kerberos.py file in your site-packages (`PYTHON_HOME\Lib\site-packages\ldap3\protocol\sasl\kerberos.py`) with the one he links to [replacement kerberos.py](https://github.com/Morgan-Stanley/treadmill/blob/master/lib/python/treadmill/ldap3kerberos.py).

You need to change the following line in the replacement kerberos.py file:

```
from treadmill import kerberoswrapper as kerberos
```

Change to

```
import winkerberos as kerberos
```

Then you can connect like this:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, Tls, SASL, GSSAPI
import ssl

tls = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_NONE, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
server = Server('server_fqdn', use_ssl=True, tls=tls)
c = Connection(server, authentication=SASL, sasl_mechanism=GSSAPI)
c.bind()
print(c.extend.standard.who_am_i())
c.unbind()
```

Replace server_fqdn with the fully qualified domain name of your AD server.

You may want to change the version value to whatever protocol your AD server uses.

If someone has a less messy method to accomplish this please chime in!

Comment: It worked! But I'm not able to do a proper monkey-patch with the gorilla package. Because the exception throws on import and not within the function. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I copied the ldap3 package from site-packages to the same place as my script and replaced the kerberos.py file in my local copy and that seemed like a cleaner approach and no monkey-patching required.  I couldn't get anywhere with the monkey-patching approach.

Comment: You may be able to monkey patch it by replacing the do_sasl_bind function for the Connection class located in ldap3/core/connection.py

Comment: Thanks for this answer - did you run into any issues with SecurityContexts and winkerberos?  For whatever reason I'm running into unknown/unreachable target

Comment: I have not run into any issues.  You replaced server_fqdn with the full name of one of your Domain Controllers?

Comment: @Jason I have.  I even ran a debugging session to verify the variable is being passed through the connection properly.  I'm able to use the other authentication methods, just struggling with sasl as a requirement because kerberos and no username/passwords.

Comment: Run the following in Powershell and check to see if GSSAPI is listed:  (Get-ADRootDSE).supportedSASLMechanisms

Comment: Yep, GSSAPI is listed.

Comment: So run this command replacing SERVERNAME with the host name (not FQDN) of your AD server.  setspn -L SERVERNAME.  If you see anything listed with ldap/ replace the server_fqdn from the above code with what is after ldap/ and see if that works.  That command lists the available SPNs on the server.

Comment: I [posted my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639090/initializesecuritycontext-the-specified-target-is-unknown-or-unreachable).  Every permutation of name looks like it's listed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the initial answer, and to avoid monkey-patching, one could utilize the following code, based on file provided [there](https://github.com/Morgan-Stanley/treadmill/blob/master/lib/python/treadmill/ldap3kerberos.py) and on the `ldap3\core\connection.py` module.

### ldap3kerberos.py

```
"""Replaces the use of python-gssapi with kerberos in ldap3.
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64
import socket

import ldap3
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPCommunicationError
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.sasl import send_sasl_negotiation
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.sasl import abort_sasl_negotiation

from ldap3.protocol.sasl.external import sasl_external
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.digestMd5 import sasl_digest_md5
from ldap3.protocol.sasl.plain import sasl_plain
from ldap3.utils.log import log, log_enabled, BASIC
from ldap3 import EXTERNAL, DIGEST_MD5, GSSAPI


import winkerberos as kerberos

NO_SECURITY_LAYER = 1
INTEGRITY_PROTECTION = 2
CONFIDENTIALITY_PROTECTION = 4


class Connection(ldap3.Connection):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_sasl_bind(self,
                     controls):
        if log_enabled(BASIC):
            log(BASIC, 'start SASL BIND operation via <%s>', self)
        self.last_error = None
        with self.connection_lock:
            result = None

            if not self.sasl_in_progress:
                self.sasl_in_progress = True
                try:
                    if self.sasl_mechanism == EXTERNAL:
                        result = sasl_external(self, controls)
                    elif self.sasl_mechanism == DIGEST_MD5:
                        result = sasl_digest_md5(self, controls)
                    elif self.sasl_mechanism == GSSAPI:
                        result = sasl_gssapi(self, controls)
                    elif self.sasl_mechanism == 'PLAIN':
                        result = sasl_plain(self, controls)
                finally:
                    self.sasl_in_progress = False

            if log_enabled(BASIC):
                log(BASIC, 'done SASL BIND operation, result <%s>', result)

            return result


def sasl_gssapi(connection, controls):
    """
    Performs a bind using the Kerberos v5 ("GSSAPI") SASL mechanism
    from RFC 4752. Does not support any security layers, only authentication!
    sasl_credentials can be empty or a tuple with one or two elements.
    The first element determines which service principal to request a ticket
    for and can be one of the following:
    - None or False, to use the hostname from the Server object
    - True to perform a reverse DNS lookup to retrieve the canonical hostname
      for the hosts IP address
    - A string containing the hostname
    The optional second element is what authorization ID to request.
    - If omitted or None, the authentication ID is used as the authorization ID
    - If a string, the authorization ID to use. Should start with "dn:" or
      "user:".
    """
    # pylint: disable=too-many-branches
    target_name = None
    authz_id = b''
    if connection.sasl_credentials:
        if (len(connection.sasl_credentials) >= 1 and
                connection.sasl_credentials[0]):
            if connection.sasl_credentials[0] is True:
                hostname = \
                    socket.gethostbyaddr(connection.socket.getpeername()[0])[0]
                target_name = 'ldap@' + hostname

            else:
                target_name = 'ldap@' + connection.sasl_credentials[0]
        if (len(connection.sasl_credentials) >= 2 and
                connection.sasl_credentials[1]):
            authz_id = connection.sasl_credentials[1].encode("utf-8")
    if target_name is None:
        target_name = 'ldap@' + connection.server.host

    gssflags = (
        kerberos.GSS_C_MUTUAL_FLAG |
        kerberos.GSS_C_SEQUENCE_FLAG |
        kerberos.GSS_C_INTEG_FLAG |
        kerberos.GSS_C_CONF_FLAG
    )

    _, ctx = kerberos.authGSSClientInit(target_name, gssflags=gssflags)

    in_token = b''
    try:
        while True:
            status = kerberos.authGSSClientStep(
                ctx,
                base64.b64encode(in_token).decode('ascii')
            )
            out_token = kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(ctx) or ''
            result = send_sasl_negotiation(
                connection,
                controls,
                base64.b64decode(out_token)
            )
            in_token = result['saslCreds'] or b''
            if status == kerberos.AUTH_GSS_COMPLETE:
                break

        kerberos.authGSSClientUnwrap(
            ctx,
            base64.b64encode(in_token).decode('ascii')
        )
        unwrapped_token = base64.b64decode(
            kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(ctx) or ''
        )

        if len(unwrapped_token) != 4:
            raise LDAPCommunicationError('Incorrect response from server')

        server_security_layers = unwrapped_token[0]
        if not isinstance(server_security_layers, int):
            server_security_layers = ord(server_security_layers)
        if server_security_layers in (0, NO_SECURITY_LAYER):
            if unwrapped_token.message[1:] != '\x00\x00\x00':
                raise LDAPCommunicationError(
                    'Server max buffer size must be 0 if no security layer'
                )
        if not server_security_layers & NO_SECURITY_LAYER:
            raise LDAPCommunicationError(
                'Server requires a security layer, but this is not implemented'
            )

        client_security_layers = bytearray([NO_SECURITY_LAYER, 0, 0, 0])
        kerberos.authGSSClientWrap(
            ctx,
            base64.b64encode(
                bytes(client_security_layers) + authz_id
            ).decode('ascii')
        )
        out_token = kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(ctx) or ''

        return send_sasl_negotiation(
            connection,
            controls,
            base64.b64decode(out_token)
        )
    except (kerberos.GSSError, LDAPCommunicationError):
        abort_sasl_negotiation(connection, controls)
        raise
```

Install **winkerberos**: `pip install winkerberos`

In your script, use the following code (`connect_timeout`, `mode` and `receive_timeout` parameters are for example only and could be omitted or changed):

```
import ldap
import ldap3kerberos

server = ldap3.Server(fqdn, connect_timeout=10, mode=ldap3.IP_V4_ONLY)
conn = ldap3kerberos.Connection(
    server, authentication=ldap3.SASL, sasl_mechanism=ldap3.GSSAPI,
    auto_bind=True, receive_timeout=10
)
```

> If you have several domain controller servers for an AD domain, ensure you are connecting to some specific server, otherwise you will get the exception:
>
> `winkerberos.GSSError: SSPI: InitializeSecurityContext: The specified target is unknown or unreachable`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer in 2024 is a little bit easier. At least for my use case.

According to the documentation you can now "just" use Kerberos as authentication method: https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bind.html#kerberos without patching any file like the answer from @dima-lituiev suggested.

I just installed `winkerberos`.

```bash
pip install winkerberos
```

And wrote the following script:

```py
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SASL, KERBEROS, ALL
server = Server("YOUR_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_URL", get_info=ALL)
c = Connection(
    server, authentication=SASL, sasl_mechanism=KERBEROS)
c.bind()

print(c.extend.standard.who_am_i())
```