# Active Directory Authentication of Logged-in User using ADODB/ADSDSOObject

Tags: python, vba, active-directory, ado

My system is connected to Active Directory and I can query it by binding using a username and password.
I noticed that I am also able to query it without explicitly providing a username and password, when using ADO or ADSDSOObject Provider (tried in Java/Python/VBA).

I would like to understand how the authentication is done in this case.

Example of first case where username and password is explicitly needed:

```
import ldap3
from ldap3.extend.microsoft.addMembersToGroups import ad_add_members_to_groups as addUsersInGroups
server = Server('172.16.10.50', port=636, use_ssl=True)
conn = Connection(server, 'CN=ldap_bind_account,OU=1_Service_Accounts,OU=0_Users,DC=TG,DC=LOCAL','Passw0rds123!',auto_bind=True)
print(conn)
```

Example of second case where no username and password is explicitly needed:

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set objCOmmand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM 'LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com' WHERE objectClass = 'Computer'"
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
```

I tried to look at the source code of the libraries but was not able to understand what is being done.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, it's using the credentials of the account running the program, or it could even be using the computer account (every computer joined to the domain has an account on the domain, with a password that no person ever sees).

Python's ldap3 package doesn't automatically do that, however, it appears there may be way to make it work without specifying credentials, using Kerberos authentication. For example, from [this issue](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/issues/907):

> I know that, for GSSAPI and GSS-SPNEGO, if you specify "authentication=SASL, sasl_mechanism=GSSAPI" (or spnego as needed) in your connection, then you don't need to specify user/password at all.

And there's also this StackOverflow question on the same topic: [Passwordless Python LDAP3 authentication from Windows client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279503/passwordless-python-ldap3-authentication-from-windows-client)