# How to install a python module which doesent have setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

So im trying to install this python module from github but it doesent have any setup.py so im wondering how else it can be installed im using python 3.6.4

https://github.com/kyb3r/Discord-Hooks

Comment: It's a single file. Just put it wherever you want and import it.

Comment: do i need to add a path or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Python module without setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714635/how-to-install-python-module-without-setup-py)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install it. Just put **discord_hooks.py** in the same directory as your python application. Then, import it using:

```
from discord_hooks import Webhook
```