# Install packages with conda - channel error

Tags: python, package, conda, channel

I am new to Python and Conda. I am trying to install a package called [DavGIS](https://github.com/gespinoza/davgis). I downloaded this package and I downloaded Anaconda. Then I opened Anaconda Prompt and tried to install the package with the command `conda install davgis`. This gave an error message regarding not begin available on current channels.

Then I tried `pip install davgis`, but this gives an error as well. In the picture the commands and errors are showed. I am using Windows 10 64-bit and Anaconda with Python 3.6

Errors installing package:
[image: error]

Comment: Please do not post error messages or code in images. The reasons are: 1) search engines cannot index an image, so no one can search for your post and find the answer; 2) blind users, who may use a screen reader, cannot read images at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install this package, because there is no package. A python package contains a file called "setup.py". And to install it with pip (or conda) it need to be referenced on their server.

If you want to use it in your project, you can copy it directly in your source folder (where your code is).

If you wanna do it without copying, you can follow this method: [How to install Python module without setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714635/how-to-install-python-module-without-setup-py)